# why static function does not have any static local variable in java

Tags: java

following Java program fails in compilation with error “Static local variables are not allowed”

```
class Myclass {

   public static void main(String args[]) { 

    System.out.println(Myfun());
   }

   static int Myfun()
   {
     static int var= 10;  

     return var += 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: what that could mean?

Comment: local variables can have only `final`

Comment: There is no use of making a local variable `static`. `static` has a special meaning and used for a certain purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a static variable (whose value will be reused in consecutive calls to the static method), declare it outside the method :

```
static int var= 10; 
static int Myfun()
{
    return var += 1;
}
```

Local variables can't be static, since a local variable exists only within the scope of a single execution of the method.

Comment: Please explain why not ,i can declare a local variable as static.

Comment: @suryadipkumar That's how the language was defined. I'm not sure about the reason for defining it this way. I think it's more readable this way. When I see a variable declared locally within a method, I don't expect its value to be retained for the next calls to the method.

Answer (score 0):

inside static block what ever you declare becomes static.

In your case, Myfun() is static and so if you want to make var as static then simply do int var=10

```
class Myclass {

   public static void main(String args[]) { 

    System.out.println(Myfun());
   }

   static int Myfun()
   {
     int var= 10;  

     return var += 1;
   }
}
```